# Why can't resolve the dependency when used from git

Tags: javascript, git, npm, dependencies, material-ui

I have cloned [@material-ui-pickers](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers) to my repository at [Princezhm/material-ui-pickers](https://github.com/Princezhm/material-ui-pickers/tree/master). I had to modify a behaviour of the library to fit my needs, but now moving to my project, it doesn't work.

My previous package JSON was:

```
blablabla....
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/pickers": "~3.1.2",
}

blablabla....
```

Now it is:

```
blablabla....
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/pickers": "github:Princezhm/material-ui-pickers",
}

blablabla....
```

Before, I was importing everything like this:

```
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
```

but now I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@material-ui/pickers'
    at webpackMissingModule (index.js?69d2:1)
    at eval (index.js?69d2:1)
    at Module../administration/src/index.js (main-b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a.js?b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a:2197)
    at __webpack_require__ (main-b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a.js?b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a:727)
    at fn (main-b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a.js?b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a:101)
    at Object.1 (main-b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a.js?b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a:78738)
    at __webpack_require__ (main-b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a.js?b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a:727)
    at main-b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a.js?b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a:794
    at main-b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a.js?b9602ab4b6e8fc30983a:797
```

Does anyone know why? If I remove the package and re-install it from `material-ui`, it works again.

Comment: Are you using Material-UI V.4?

Comment: @Idan yes. in my project it is, the problem comes when I try to use the `@material-ui/pickers` ..... as far as I see, the problem is that using the git reference, wont make use of the build version of the library

Comment: @PrinceHernandez I presume you need to build the app and publish it https://github.com/Princezhm/material-ui-pickers/blob/next/package.json#L5 - I don't see `index.js` in the root, that's why the module can be missed